# str.contains to match entire string - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to check whether a certain list includes elements of another list.

I am using the following line of code:

```
check = df_1['website'].str.contains(df_2['website'].tolist()[i])
```

The problem that I am facing now is that I receive false positives, if the first df partially includes the strings in the second one.

For example
I am looking to find if the following string in df_2['website'] is contained in df_1['website']:

> sample_text_to_check

Since df_1['website'] contains the following string:

> text_to_check

It results in a positive match.
I would like to check for exact matches only (i.e. the entire string is matched and not only some letters within it.

How can I do that?
The lists is 200k lines long and contains many different strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just place `^` and `$` boundary markers around the string:

```py
check = df_1['website'].str.contains(r'^' + df_2['website'].tolist()[i] + r'$')
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain me what that is doing? I do not know regex

Comment: Sure, `^Pietro$` matches a string which exactly matches `Pietro` from start to end.